# Using SUMIF in Excel/Google Sheets

Tags: excel, sum, sumifs, google-sheets

I am creating a billable hours sheet in google sheets and would like to exclude line items that i set as not billable

In column B is the amount of hours worked
In column E is the rate per hour
In column D is Billable "Yes/No"
In Column F is Cost for that line item

Ideally I would like column F's total to be conditional based on column D's answer, so:

4 hours worked, at $20/hr, is billable would be $80
4 hours worked, at $20/hr, is NOT billable would be $0

Can someone please help me with the proper conditional SUMIF formula to get this started?

Comment: should it be separate formula for each line or total formula for column F?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean. i'd like the formula to be repeated down every line. like (B2*E2*1_IF(D2=YES)) or (B2*E2*0_IF(D2=NO)), and the # of row changes according to the line it is on.

Comment: maybe: `=IF(D2="YES",B2*E2,0)` or `=B2*E2*(D2="YES")`

Comment: let us know if it helps:)

Comment: That works! Very awesome :) How do I select your answer as the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As follow up from comments, next formulas works in `F2` and copied down:

```
=IF(D2="YES",B2*E2,0)
```

or

```
=B2*E2*(D2="YES")
```